# Wicked PDF font size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I have a Rails 3 app that creates a PDF using the gem 'wicked_pdf'.

I have an HTML page that looks fine online. But, the font is too large when it becomes a pdf.

Here is my controller code:

```
  def invoice_pdf
    @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:invoice_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "invoice.pdf",
               font_size: 8,
               disable_links: true,
               template: 'invoices/_invoice_pdf.html.erb'
      end
    end
  end
```

The `font_size: 8` doesn't seem to work.  I can change it to any value and the pdf text looks the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
body {
  font-family: 'OpenSansRegular';
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

Add this css in your html.erb file.